# How to preload ajax data before putting it in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I have this script for fetching data with ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data: { modelID:id },
  type: 'post',
  success: function(result){
    $(result).load(function(){
       $('.view_'+id).html(result)
       $('.view_'+id).find('.brandModelGallery').bxSlider({})
       $('.view_'+id).addClass('loaded')
    })
  }
})
```

But I'd like to attach the `$('.view_'+id).html(result)` only after the data has been received, otherwise the page load is very ugly. What should I add to the success response to make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your `result` is not null and have some response inside it.

Please change your function as below

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data: { modelID:id },
  type: 'post',
  success: function(result){
    if(result != null && typeof result != 'undefined' && result.length > 0){
         $(result).load(function(){
             $('.view_'+id).html(result)
             $('.view_'+id).find('.brandModelGallery').bxSlider({})
             $('.view_'+id).addClass('loaded')
         })
    }
  }
})
```

May this help you.

Comment: You should check it as result != undefined and not result != 'undefined'

Comment: for whatever the reason `$(result).load(function(){ ... })` doesn't return anything, even without checking if `result != null` and all the rest of that `if` statement. Do you have an idea of why that could be?

Comment: @Xeen you got success response or is there any erro or your ajax call is fail ?

Answer (score 0):

```
         $.ajax({ 
                  url: 'ajax.php',
                  data: { modelID:id },
                  type: 'post',
                  success: function(result){
         if(result!=null || result!=undefined || result.length > 0)
    {
                    $(result).load(function(){
                       $('.view_'+id).html(result)
                       $('.view_'+id).find('.brandModelGallery').bxSlider({})
                       $('.view_'+id).addClass('loaded')

                    })
                  }
                 }
                })

        //Just check if your result is not null(data is fetched) before attaching it :)
```

Answer (score 0):

check this tooo....

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {modelID: id},
        success: function (result) //we're calling the response json array 'permissions'
        {
            if (result != null && result.length > 0) {
                $('.view_' + id).html(result)
                $('.view_' + id).find('.brandModelGallery').bxSlider({})
                $('.view_' + id).addClass('loaded')
            }
        }, beforeSend: function () {
// SHOW THE SPINNER
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            // HIDE THE SPINNER
        }

    });
```